# Вопрос по выравниванию высоты блоков с помощью flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью flexbox сделать, чтобы при выравнивании высоты карточек изменялась высота определенного внутреннего элемента? В моем случае блока с белым фоном.

Comment: Прикладывайте код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.list__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: .2em solid blue;
  margin-left: 1em;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
.list__item__block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .5em;
  border-bottom: .1em solid blue;
}
.list__item__block:nth-child(3) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='list'>
  <div class='list__item'>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 1</div>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 2</div>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very big block 3</div>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='list__item'>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 1</div>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 2</div>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 3</div>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='list__item'>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 1</div>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 2</div>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 3</div>
    <div class='list__item__block'>Block 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!